# How do I set Liquibase with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, liquibase

I'm working on a project that uses spring-boot, Maven, liquibase. So, I'm getting an error when I run my project and the liquibase
configuration is set up to update when maven is executing.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find changelog location: class path resource [db-scripts/db.master.xml] (please add changelog or check your Liquibase configuration)
```

I saw that pom.xml have a tag excludes with my DB script's path. I believe that maven is erasing that path before the liquibase run.

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase uses from changelog files. You had to add the file.

Comment: Hi Tomasz 
I had a changelog file in there but didn't work yet. If I remove the following code of my pom.xml. It works fine.

`code`
<excludes>
          <exclude>db-scripts/**</exclude>
</excludes>
`code`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "If I remove the following code of my pom.xml. It works fine. code <excludes> <exclude>db-scripts/**</exclude> </excludes>" it is a feature, not bug in Maven. When you exclude something from project it means that the project does not have the files which Liquibase needs that it why it does not work. AFAIK

Comment: Ok. I understood. What can I do? I need those files to liquibase works but after it, I want to erase those files.

Comment: Wow...." I want to erase those files." why? You could't delete those files. Either working Liquibase either deletion those files.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know why my Team leader want to do that but is configure to work like that =/ 
Maybe I have an option to exchange execution sequence of Maven's plugin.